# Return Null if Joining table does not have the particular foreign id

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a query that displays organizations and the number of cards so i joined 2 table,
This is the query ,

```
SELECT o.organisation_id, organisation_name, IFNULL(COUNT(bus_operator_card_id),"--") num_cards
FROM `organisation` o 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `bus_operator_cards` boc ON  o.organisation_id = boc.organisation_id 
WHERE o.org_type_id =5
AND boc.is_active = true GROUP BY o.organisation_id  ORDER BY o.organisation_id DESC;
```

This is the result I'm getting

```
-----------------------------------------------------
organisation_id | organisation_name   |   num_cards |
-----------------------------------------------------
   1            | Luxury Bus Services | 1  
   3            | Test test           | 5
```

My Desired Result

```
-----------------------------------------------------
organisation_id | organisation_name   |   num_cards |
-----------------------------------------------------
   1            | Luxury Bus Services | 1           
   2            | Power tools         | --   
   3            | Test test           | 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditions on all but the first table should be in the `ON` clause, not the `WHERE` for a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT o.organisation_id, o.organisation_name, 
       COALESCE(CAST(COUNT(bus_operator_card_id) as CHAR), '--') as num_cards
FROM `organisation` o LEFT OUTER JOIN
     `bus_operator_cards` boc 
     ON o.organisation_id = boc.organisation_id AND boc.is_active = true 
WHERE o.org_type_id = 5
GROUP BY o.organisation_id
ORDER BY o.organisation_id DESC;
```

Your `WHERE` clause is filtering out non-matches which turns the outer join to an inner join.

Note that the resulting column is a string, not a number.  Because of type precedence rules, you need to convert the count to a string.  However, I would recommend using `0` or `NULL` for the value:

```
SELECT o.organisation_id, o.organisation_name, 
       COUNT(boc.bus_operator_card_id) as num_cards
```

Given the name of the column `0` makes more sense to me than `'--'`.